# How to fix Identifier doesn't match expected value error when connection to mongodb with kerberos?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, database-connection, kerberos

I'm trying to connect to mongodb server with kerberos using keytab and principal with a java application on a linux server.

I doubled checked that the keytab and principal are the right ones.

Succeeded in connecting manually from the server (not from the java code).

However, I keep getting this error which won't let me touch the database:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoConnection': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=GSSAPI, userName='X', source='$external', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)

        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)

        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)

        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)

        at com.Application.main(Application.java:40)

       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)

        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)

        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)

        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=GSSAPI, userName=’X', source='$external', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:173)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$300(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:70)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:179)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:156)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:398)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:115)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:101)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:92)

        at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:126)

        at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:136)

        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:528)

        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:492)

        at com.mongodb.operation.CreateCollectionOperation.execute(CreateCollectionOperation.java:381)

        at com.mongodb.operation.CreateCollectionOperation.execute(CreateCollectionOperation.java:57)

        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:206)

        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.executeCreateCollection(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:304)

        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.createCollection(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:261)

        at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoDatabaseImpl.createCollection(MongoDatabaseImpl.java:256)

        at com.connections.MongoConnection.init(MongoConnection.java:52)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)

        ... 26 common frames omitted

Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed

        at jdk.security.jgss/com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)

        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:53)

        ... 55 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:773)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:266)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:196)

        at jdk.security.jgss/com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)

        ... 56 common frames omitted

Caused by: sun.security.krb5.KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:70)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:226)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:237)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCredsSingle(CredentialsUtil.java:482)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:340)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:314)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:169)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:490)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:697)

        ... 59 common frames omitted

Caused by: sun.security.krb5.Asn1Exception: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.init(TGSRep.java:65)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.<init>(TGSRep.java:60)

        at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:55)

        ... 67 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You can see example Java code [connecting to MongoDB server using Kerberos authentication](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/driver/tutorials/authentication/).

Comment: @prasad_ There is nothing there with keytab.